# PES 2015 - BAL World Player of the Year

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2015

I was wondering if someone can suggest a fast way to become the World Player of the Year quickly. I tried to use Messi (because he wins the award if you skip all the games) with perfect stats, played really each game in the season (friendly-games, national team, league, cup and CL) until the award, scored in this time 300+ goals and 40+ assists and have an overall rating of 8.9. Of course I was MVP in all of the games. Also, I won the European best player award, but I did not even make it to the Top 3 in the World Best Players.

Is there anything I could do except for playing another season? I am not a big fan of the BAL mode and would like to get the trophy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how PES decides who is the best player, but I think it's the player who "grew" the most during the previous year. Or it at least is part of the equation.

The earliest I managed to achieve this was with a new player after two seasons (so you have to start the third to actually get the award), but on a lower difficulty level.